# Use $gte mongo operator if date is in string format in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have datetime field like  **{datetime:"Tue May 19 2023 08:00:00 GMT-0400 (hora de Bolivia)"}**  in the database. Now I want to perform $gte on datetime field that is in string format like below:

```
 Records.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    datetime: {
                        $gte: new Date()
                    }
                }
            }
        ]).exec();
```

I am getting empty array in response.

Could anyone please help me out to resolve this query.

Comment: Can you share what is the type of `datetime` ? (what does it say in MongoDB compass?)

Comment: Yes, It’s a String

Comment: Ah, now I understand. So you need to parse this. Can you store it in the database differently or is this something someone has given you?

Comment: Parsing it in MongoDB may not be your best option, I personally would use some other programming language (e.g. Node.js) to first convert all of them into the `Date` type.

Comment: You could also try to use `$dateFromString`

Comment: Im also using nodejs but i cannot change the data type it has to be string. Any workaround using same data type.

Comment: If you store the string as an ISO string it would make it much easier to Parse, like `2023-05-13T20:03:43.590Z`

Comment: dateFromString Is unable to parse the string.

Comment: Well, you'll probably have to do some work for $dateFromString (like $substr and choose the correct format)

Comment: I would appreciate if you could share the example code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253644/discussion-between-cody--and-ch3t).

Comment: You should **never** store date values as string, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. below is the valid query

```
Records.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      datetime: {
        $dateFromString: {
          "dateString": {
            "$substr": [
              "$datetime",
              0,
              23
            ]
          },
          
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      datetime: {
        $gt: new Date()
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: How can this work when your data contains the month as name?